# Is it possible to run a motor inside a black box by applying an EM field, without knowing anything about the motor?

Tags: motor

Is it possible to run an electric motor located within a container by applying an external EM field over the container, if you do not know anything about the motor?

The container with the motor would basically be like an unknown black box. It would have to run solely from the power it gets from the external EM field.

Is this possible?

**Update:**
Apologies for not providing sufficient information the first time around. This question came to my mind when I was thinking about different potential security weaknesses in modern cars (the type that would allow someone break in). I had read that there were supposedly a device that allowed thieves to unlock car doors without the actual key. So I started wondering if there was a way to apply an EMF field to the car door to run the window motor from the outside. If there is then this would be a security problem.

Comment: Probably not. Motors are generally designed to interact as little as possible (both radiating and receiving) with external fields.

Comment: Schrodinger's motor might be running in the sealed box, or it might not be...  apologies in advance

Comment: Not likely. Most motors stators would shield the rotor from any magnetic field from outside.

Comment: Well if you connect an antenna to a rectifier to the motor. Apply a sufficient (time-varying) EM field and the motor will turn.

Comment: Is this a sort of conceptual or theoretical experiment, or do you have a specific use case in mind? BTW I think it is impossible to answer positively without knowing really *anything* about what kind of motor is in the black box.

Comment: For example, I could imagine some sort of superconducting coils arrangement, without metal shielding, in a field generated by a permanent magnet, that could begin to spin if excited by an EM pulse. Does this count as a motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact-less phone chargers use magnetic field coupling between the charger base and the "thing" to be charged and a few watts of power are easily transferable. This can easily activate a small motor. This relies of course on something being attached to the motor but if you truly "do not know anything about the motor" then that is likely to prove the killer because the motor may be stalled mechanically, broken etc..

Maybe you need to clarify this.